# How to display multiple row in listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am new to android. Recently I am trying to develop an app which could fetch data from php and display it into android listview. I have successfully done that. But problem is showing the data into listview. I have successfully displayed one item per row. But I need to display two or more than that . I have seen many tutorials , but I have failed to realize those tutorials as I am new in android. My code is below , please help me what should I do now.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

new TheTask().execute();
}
   class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
  {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String str = null;
    try
    {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/BSDI/show.php");
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
      str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());     
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return str;

  }

//public void execute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    String response = result.toString();
    try {

        ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray new_array = new JSONArray(response);


        for(int i = 0, count = new_array.length(); i< count; i++)
        {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new_array.getJSONObject(i);
                stringArray.add(jsonObject.getString("title").toString());


            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.test_tuh,stringArray);           




        ListView list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        tv.setText("error2");
    } 


}
```

This is my json response

```
[{"title":"notice1","notice":"details..."},{"title":"exam","notice":"Our exam will be held on 20th january..."}]
```

Comment: String result.toString() ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom **ArrayAdapter**. follow [this link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-custom-adapter-with-imageview.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Use this to json parsing in listview](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView_collage_label_imageno"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
             android:text="No"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:textSize="20sp" />
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView_collage_label"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_collage_label_imageno"
             android:layout_below="@+id/textView_collage_label_imageno"
             android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
             android:text="Label Name"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

---

baseAdapter

```
   package com.example.generaldemo;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class CommonBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        ArrayList<String> labelname_array = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> labelno_array = new ArrayList<String>();

        Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;


        public CommonBaseAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> label_array, ArrayList<String> lno)
        {
            context = c;
            labelname_array = label_array;
            labelno_array = lno;
            //labelno_array = no_array;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return labelname_array.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = convertView;
            Holder holder;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v == null) {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                holder = new Holder();
                holder.tv_labelname = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView_collage_label);
                holder.tv_labelno = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_collage_label_imageno);
                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (Holder) v.getTag();
            }


            holder.tv_labelname.setText(labelname_array.get(position));
            holder.tv_labelno.setText(labelno_array.get(position));


            //holder.tv_labelno.setText(labelno_array.get(position));

            return v;
        }
        public class Holder
        {
            TextView tv_labelname,tv_labelno;
        }

    }
```

---

main activity

```
package com.example.generaldemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import it.sephiroth.android.wheel.view.Wheel;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listview;

    ArrayList<String> label_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> label_no = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        //add json value in arraylist in your code
        label_name.add("Java");
        label_name.add("PHP");
        label_name.add("Android");

        label_no.add("1");
        label_no.add("2");
        label_no.add("3");

        CommonBaseAdapter adapter = new CommonBaseAdapter(MainActivity.this, label_name,label_no);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried your code and it works. But in your code the data are static. And my data is dynamic. I have firstly fetched json data from php using AsyncTask and then parsed it then displayed into listview. Due to new android developer I am having problem using your codes. I can not finding out how to use(displying multiple row listview dynamic data) your code after fetching and parsing json data.